# AppStore submission architecture error 9000 armv7

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval, cpu-architecture

I've already pushed few versions of app in past few months. However now I have an error about architectures, while I didn't change anything.

---

My project:
Architectures: armv7, arm64 - $(ARCHS_STANDARD)
Valid Architecures: arm64, armv7, armv7s

My target:
Architectures: armv7, arm64 - $(ARCHS_STANDARD)
Valid Architecures: arm64, armv7

---

Subproject target:
Architectures: armv7, arm64 - $(ARCHS_STANDARD)
Valid Architecures: armv7

Subproject target:
Architectures: armv7, arm64 - $(ARCHS_STANDARD)
Valid Architecures: arm64, armv7

---

Pods target:
Architectures: Standerd Architectures (64-bit Intel) (x84_64) - $(ARCHS_STANDARD)
Valid Architecures: i386 x86_64

Pods targets (all the same):
Architectures: armv7, arm64 - $(ARCHS_STANDARD)
Valid Architecures: arm64, armv7, armv7s

---

[image]

The thing is even more strange as first time I've validated the build it passed and was ok. Then when I've tried to submit there was an error. When I've tried to validate again the same build I've got an error. When I've archived again with exactly the same settings, validation of new archive also doesn't work.

What to do to fix it? Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to archive without your device pluged in (yes, disconnect iPhone). Or better: set Build Active Architectures to No.

Comment: Lol I've just noticed that in release 'build active architecture only' is also set to 'yes', while it should be 'NO' in release and 'YES' in debug. Oh so stupid I didn't think about it! Thanks SOOO much!